# Nested loop in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in pyspark as below

```
123,2016-09-21,[s3://mybucket/1/,s3://mybucket/2/,s3://mybucket/3/]
```

where I iterate as below:

```
for path in s3_list:
    for i in range(len(path.S3_path)):
        model(path.S3_path[i].strip())
        print "the looping number"+ str(i)
    model1(path.Id.strip(),path.dt.strip())
```

I need some help on how to do this using Flatmap and Map. Below is the code i started with:

```
Slist = lambda s3_list: (y for y in s3_list)
S3path= lambda path: (model(path.S3_path[i].strip()) for i in xrange(len(path.S3_path)))

sc.parallelize(s3_list).flatMap(Slist).flatMap(S3path)
```

How to call the function model1 in the above code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell us what really happened, by pressing the `edit` button above and add it into your post?

Comment: How and where do you want to store `model()` and `model1()` functions results?

Comment: The results of model() is a dataframe (temptable). The temptable is written back to S3 as parquet.